# How to make on xml field an attribute of another field?

Tags: xml, xslt-1.0, xslt

I have the following xml file:

```
<generic_etd>
  <dc.contributor>NSERC</dc.contributor>
  <dc.creator>gradstudent</dc.creator>
  <dc.contributor>John Smith</dc.contributor>
  <dc.contributor.role>Advisor</dc.contributor.role>
  <dc.date>2013-05-07</dc.date>
  <dc.format>30 pages</dc.format>
  <dc.format>545709 bytes</dc.format>
  <dc.contributor>Jane Smith</dc.contributor>
  <dc.contributor.role>Committee Member</dc.contributor.role>
</generic_etd>
```

Which I would like to transformed into the following using xslt 1.0:

```
<etd_ms>
  <etd_ms:contributor>NSERC</etd_ms:contributor>
  <etd_ms:creator>gradstudent</etd_ms:creator>
  <etd_ms:contributor role="Advisor">John Smith</etd_ms:contributor>
  <etd_ms:date>2013-05-07</etd_ms:date>
  <etd_ms:format>30 pages</etd_ms:format>
  <etd_ms:format>545709 bytes</etd_ms:format>
  <etd_ms:contributor role="Committee Member">Jane Smith</etd_ms:contributor>
</etd_ms>
```

I can do the etd_ms substitution but what I am having difficulty with is inserting the contributor.role line as an attribute of the contributor line. I am new at xslt transforms so this has me stumped. Any suggestions?

Here is the code so far (I have left out the beginning and end tags for brevity. I also I want to thank Navin Rawat who provided this much more succinct version of code then what I originally had):

```
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" encoding="UTF-8"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>

</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="name()='generic_etd'">
            <etd_ms:thesis>
                <xsl:apply-templates/>
            </etd_ms:thesis>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:variable name="newtag" select="concat('etd_ms:',substring-after(name(),'.'))"/>
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="contains($newtag, '.')">
                    <xsl:element name="{substring-before($newtag,'.')}">
                        <xsl:apply-templates/>
                    </xsl:element>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:element name="{$newtag}">
                        <xsl:apply-templates/>
                    </xsl:element>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Edit your post and include what you have already done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to figure out the solution myself. Essentially I created a template that I call from the previous xslt file I included in the original question. Here is the template used:

```
<xsl:template name="contributor-role">
  <xsl:param name="element-tag"/>
  <xsl:choose>
    <!-- check if the next element is a contributer role -->
    <xsl:when test="following-sibling::dc.contributor.role[1]">
      <xsl:element name="{$element-tag}">
        <!-- add the role as an attribute of the current element-->
        <xsl:attribute name="role">
          <xsl:value-of select="following-sibling::dc.contributor.role[1]"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
      </xsl:element>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
      <!-- else process the element normally -->
      <xsl:element name="{$element-tag}">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
      </xsl:element>
    </xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```